# How to translate "pretty-print"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

The terms *pretty-print(er,ing)* are often used in programming to designate a kind of function that outputs a human-readable text, in a more pleasant way than a "raw" representation of the data being printed.

I found the following translations online, but I don't know which one (if any) is more commonly used (or if the English form is used without translation):

- Impressão bonita
- Impressão formatada
- Impressão alinhada
- Impressor-embelezador
- Impressão elegante

Comment: I've never heard any of these. At least when the "output" is code, the automatic code organization is usually called "formatação".

Comment: So "formatação" would be the term for *pretty-printing*? And *printing* would be simply "impressão"? By the way, your answer helped me find [this Spanish SE question about the same term](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/), but it seems to diverge towards *indenting*, so I'm not sure it helps much.

Comment: "Formatação" doesn't mean the exact same thing as "pretty-printing", but it's the closest in meaning that I'm aware of. Yes, printing means "impressão". About the indenting, to pretty-print code is basically just organize the indenting. Some also fixes capitalization, but usually this is done while typing.

Comment: It seems your comment might be the best answer this question will have, so please turn it into an answer so that I can accept it. I'll still wait some time in case someone else replies, but your comment is as good an answer as any other.

Comment: Não sei de nenhuma tradução estabelecida, mas «formatação amigável» parece-me uma hipótese.

Answer (score 1):

**Texto legível** (by Google)

It's the most common way here.

"Texto amigável" I think that it's another alternative, if you want to means a kind of function that outputs a human-readable text. It's like friendly URLs.

"Formatação" has the sense of "pretty text". Is a text that have correct indentation, bolds, italics, etc.